# Is there a one line command to make chmod interactive?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I am looking for something like:

```
ls | ask_yes_no_for_each_file | chmod +x the_files_approved
```

Or similar syntax.

Also could work on other commands that you want individual confirmation for.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This does what you are looking for:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -L1 -p0 chmod +x
```

This uses `find` rather than `ls` because, generally, [parsing `ls` output is unreliable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  This form, using `find`, however, will work with filenames even if they contain newlines or other difficult characters.

Explanation

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0`

  This selects the files.  This can be customized using any of find's many options.  The option `print0` tells `find` to print the file names in a null-separated list.  This is the only reliable to transmit lists of file names.
- `xargs -L1 -p0 chmod +x`

  This takes the null-separated list of file names generated by `find` and applies your command to them.

The `-L1` option tells `xargs` to work on only one file name at a time.  The `-p` option tells `xargs` to prompt for approval before continuing.  The `-0` option tells `xargs` to use the null character as the delimiter between file names.

[I was unaware of the `-p` option to `xargs` until @kwan pointed it out.]

Comment: You can make the `find` command POSIX compatible by using [`-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-). Don't think there's any way to make the whole thing POSIX compatible though.

Comment: This syntax gives me a warning `find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.` So it works with the `-maxdepth 1` before the `-type f`, as: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -L1 -p0 chmod +x`.

Comment: @Harvey You are correct: I updated the answer to remove that warning.

Answer (score 25):

You can use `xargs`.

eg:

```
ls|xargs -I path -p chmod +x path
```

Option `-p`:   **Prompt the user about whether to run each command line and read a line from the terminal.  Only run the  command line if the response starts with 'y' or 'Y'.**

Comment: +1 I like your use of `xargs -p` so much that I will copy it.

Comment: Perfect! And very simple way to make most any command interactive. Thanks.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Kroltan - why would anyone would use a newline in a file name?

Comment: @nbubis It can happen: go to a terminal and type `touch "a very long file name` and press enter. See the line continuation and simply type the closing quote and press enter again. tadaa, newline in filename. Out of laziness to retype a long filename.

Comment: @nbubis I use OS X, where spaces (and apostrophes and other things that confuse xargs) *will* appear in filenames. Use `printf "%s\0" * | xargs -0 ...` to avoid problems.

Comment: @nbubis - I felt the same way until I noticed that I had copy and pasted some text for file names from web pages and ended up with some names with newlines in them. Sooner or later, I'll have to figure out a fancy find command to go through and sanitize all of them.